# What are the alternatives to the Gripewater?

Tags: health

[The Gripewater seems to be not so healthy](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/3673/2221).
What are the healthy alternatives to the Gripewater?

Answers with references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It depends where you are. In the UK there is infacol, dentinox colic drops, and a few other brands. I have no references to go with this, my own personal experience is that infacol didn't seem to work and dentinox did. This may be due to my own child rather than the treatment itself.

The think I found that contributed most to improving my child's stomach was changing formula and bottle types. We started out with tommee tippee botttles and SMA formula, then we changed to dr browns bottles and aptamil formula. The differences were remarkable. So if you are bottle feeding consider making changes to those things before trying a colic remedy.

Comment: same here, different formula, soothing music and getting baby to play or see a colorful painting and later a poster which he particularly liked